# N-Queens algorithm. Plot Twist: The Queen is a Knight too

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

Trying to modify the `N-Queens` algorithm for a Knights' movement set, on a `N*N` board. In my case I was testing it on a `4*4` and `8*8` board.

My algorithm, resp. my recursion fails dealing with the Knight because it sometimes needs to skip a row. You don't need to skip rows if it's only a Queens' movement since you have exactly `1` Queen per row.

The problem is in my `Solve()` function, because my recursion is tied to the number of Queens. Normally the number of queens per board should be `8`. However incorporating a Knights' movement reduces the number to `6`. Thus, I think, the recursion does not go deep enough *(Only 6 rows deep, not 8)*.

For example a solution on a `4*4` board is `(1,1)` and `(4,2)` *(row*col)*. But it isn't capable of skipping lines 2 and 3.

*How do I make the recursion look through all the rows while being able to skip some.*

```
    static int[] board = new int[9];
    static int cnt = 0;

    static bool CanPlace(int row, int col) // eg. x[1] = 2, 1st row 2nd col has a Queen
    {            
        for (int j = 1; j <= (row - 1); j++)
        {               
            if (board[j] == col || Math.Abs(board[j] - col) == Math.Abs(j - row)) return false;
            if ((Math.Abs(board[j] - col) - 1)  ==  Math.Abs(j - row)) return false;                
            //The line of code above should work for all of the possible moves of the Knight. 
            //At least it does for a 4x4 board, for the first two lines. 
            //Giving a pair of results = (1,1)(2,4) and the mirror (1,4)(2,1)
        }
        return true;
    }

    static void Solve(int row, int boardSize)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= boardSize; col++)
        {
            if (CanPlace(row, col)) //This only triggers 6 times per board
            {
                board[row] = col;
                if (row == boardSize - 2)   // Here i tried to fix it but the bottom rows get sacrificed               
                    PrintBoard();                   
                else
                    Solve(row + 1, boardSize);                   
            }                    
        }        
    }

    static void PrintBoard()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();           
        cnt++;
        for (int i = 1; i <= board.Length-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= board.Length - 1; j++)               
                if (board[i] == j) Console.Write("Q");                   
                else Console.Write(".");                    
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= board.Length - 1; i++)            
            Console.Write("{0},", board[i]);               

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Solve(1, 8);
        Console.WriteLine("\nNumber of solutions: {0}\n",cnt);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this gets harder.  You need a couple of modifications to the earlier problem, which makes this a worthy programming exercise.

1. Maintain a count of how many queens you've placed.
2. Allow skipping a row: not placing a queen isn't failure; you simply don't update the count.
3. You need to retain the best solution (greatest number of queens) found so far, and keep going until you run the first queen past the halfway point.

Note that you do *not* have to allow for no queen in the first row.  If there is a solution without any queen in the first row, there is a corresponding solution with as many queens, merely shifted one row.

Is that enough to get you moving?

Comment: I think the first step is to prove a solution exists

Comment: @Steve -- that occurs when the returned count is 0.

Comment: isn't this brutal force though...the solution to original n queen is greedy

Comment: We do need an exhaustive search: a greedy algorithm doesn't necessarily produce an optimal solution.  Sometimes, we have to leave a blank row in the middle.

Comment: I also note a slight mental error: there will *never* be a return value of 0.  You can always place at least one queen.